# How to set logLevel in a pyspark job

Tags: pyspark, virtualenv

I'm trying to set the log level in a pyspark job. I'm not using the spark shell, so I can't just do what it advises and call sc.setLogLevel(newLevel), since I don't have an sc object.

A lot of sources say to just modify the log4j.properties, but I don't know where to find/put that file. I used pip install pyspark in a virtual environment, so I don't have a $SPARK_HOME environment variable that I've set (the sources usually say the log4j.properties is in the $SPARK_HOME).

I hope I can call this programmatically, but I don't know where to call setLogLevel. Right now my setup code is just this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test-mf").getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 10):

The SparkSession object has an attribute to get the SparkContext object, and calling setLogLevel on it does change the log level being used:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test-mf").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")
```

Comment: how to set that property before `getOrCreate()` which emits message to `stderr`?

Comment: This didn't work for me. The WARN level is still active.

Answer (score 1):

In order to suppress messages that are emitted by getOrCreate, you'll need to pass config options to the sparksession builder using `appName(...).config(...).config(...).getOrCreate()`

Use the following config properties to override the default log4j properties:

```
    ...
    .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:custom_log4j.properties")

    ...
    .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:custom_log4j.properties")
```

The following custom_log4j.properties file is sufficient to mute warnings on my system:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Set the log level to ERROR for everything
log4j.logger.org.apache=ERROR
```